# Kernel panic from Linux Mint guest in VirtualBox: "Attempted to kill init!", "Some program might be trying to access hardware directly"

Tags: linux, windows-8, virtualbox, linux-mint, kernel-panic

I have a Asus X201E netbook with preinstalled Windows 8 64 bit. I wanted to install there Linux on Virtual Machine. I installed Virtualbox 4.3.0, downloaded newest Mint - Mint 15 32 bit. So, my host OS is Windows 8, I would like to have Mint15/Ubuntu 13.04/Xubuntu 13.04 as guest. I created a VDI disk on C: partition and tried to install Mint but I got such error:

[image]

Heres my VirtualBox log file: http://pastebin.com/x4e0x0Qf. Im not very good in hardware, so please give simple answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the BIOS and Enable the Virtualization Machine. Microsoft has put some blocks on Windows 8.